# android gradle error: Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root

Tags: android, module, gradle, settings, android-studio

I've just updated my Android Studio this morning to version 0.4.2 with gradle 1.9.
Before updating Gradle was compiling well however, after updating it has started to show an error each time I've tried to compile or refresh Gradle configurations. 
The message is always the same:

```
"Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root."
Content root: 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/AndroidWork/Project/modules'
Given path: 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\AndroidWork\Project\src\testLive\java'
```

My folder structure is:

> /Project
>
> > -|modules/
> >
> > > -|moduleA
> > >
> > > -|moduleB
> >
> > -|src/
> >
> > > -main/
> > >
> > > > > -java
> > > > >
> > > > > -res
> > > > >
> > > > > -AndroidManifest
> > >
> > > -dev/
> > >
> > > > > -java
> > > > >
> > > > > -res
> > > > >
> > > > > -AndroidManifest
> > >
> > > -qa/
> > >
> > > > > -java
> > > > >
> > > > > -res
> > > > >
> > > > > -AndroidManifest
> > >
> > > -live/
> > >
> > > > > -java
> > > > >
> > > > > -res
> > > > >
> > > > > -AndroidManifest
>
> -|build.gradle
>
> -|settings.gradle --> here i've added the modules' information [include ':modules:moduleA', ':modules:moduleB']

when dev, qa & live are different flavours.

Something I cannot understand it's why gradle is asking for "testLive" when I haven't added this test folder.

Could someone help me with this issue?

As I said, before updating all was working properly and without any problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug and attach the contents of your `idea.log` file (Help menu > Show log)

Comment: Bug published, thanks.

Comment: It's https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64666 for others who come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue has been plaguing me for 2 days, ever since I upgraded to AS 0.4.2. I searched everywhere for a solution, including the open bug Scott Barta mentioned. For me the issue seemed to be in my root-level build.gradle file (the one that sits next to settings.gradle).

Check this build.gradle file, and if you have the following line of code in there **comment it out** and try to sync again with AS. The line of code is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

I'm not sure why I personally had this in there, but I suspect it was because I based my gradle setup on example code. Likely the same example code you may have based yours on. Anyways, this was the fix for me. Hope it works for you too.