# Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm getting this error in IDEA 15 when I try to import the [jmonkeyengine](https://github.com/jMonkeyEngine/jmonkeyengine) project:

> Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root. Content root: '/home/kevin/Projects/IDEA/jmonkeyengine/jme3-jbullet' Given path: '/home/kevin/Projects/IDEA/jmonkeyengine/jme3-bullet/src/common/java'

The first line is identical to an error that was discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024061/android-gradle-error-cant-register-given-path-of-type-source-because-its-ou).  It was apparently related to a bug that was introduced in Android Studio 0.4.2 and [fixed in 0.5.0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56367).

The fact that this still occurs in IDEA 15 makes me think there must be more to it.  And it seems to me that you *shouldn't* be able to reference sources outside the content root.  Which brings me to my question: **Has the IDEA team decided that this is working as intended, and projects should not be set up this way?**

Note [comment #4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56367#c4) on the AS bug report:

> I have the same issue, and it's preventing me from importing a Java test module that loads sources from its sibling Android project (necessary since the Java and Android Gradle plugins aren't compatible).

This also strikes me as unnecessary and wrong, which deepens my suspicion that IDEA is actually working as it should, and it's the project structure that's broken.

Answer (score 0):

The [corresponding IDEA bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122577) is marked fixed in version 16, which is in [early access](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/12/intellij-idea-16-eap-starts-the-faster-release-cycle/) as of a few days ago.

Comment: This is great, however in order to overcome this issue temporarily I simply comment out the affected lines in the gradle build files and then the project will import just fine. After that you can uncomment the lines again but you will have to comment the lines out again if you for some reason need to reimport the project. Glad to see IntelliJ getting support for this even though I think it's the project structure which is wrong.